# UICollectionView does not have a member named dequeueResuableCellWithReuseIdentifier

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I'm getting an interesting error in XCode 6:

`UICollectionView does not have a member named dequeueResuableCellWithReuseIdentifier`

The error appears on the second line ("let cell...") in the following function:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView?, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // Configure the cell

        let cell:FightCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FightCollectionViewCell
        let battle = self.lobbyData.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as PFUser

        PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getOnlineUsers", withParameters: [:], target: nil, selector: "block:")

            func block(users: NSArray, error:NSError!){
                if(error == nil){

                    let user:PFUser = (users as NSArray).lastObject as PFUser
                    let avatarObject = user["avatar"] as PFObject!

                    avatarObject.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (object: PFObject!, error: NSError!) in
                        if error == nil {
                            let imageFile = object["image"] as PFFile
                            imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                                (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                                if error == nil {
                                    let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                                    cell.avatarImageView.image = image
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
           }


        return cell
    }
```

This code did not throw an error in XCode 6 beta. Why does XCode now have an issue with that line of code? I'm new to iOS development so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your method signature, my guess is that your error message is *really* `UICollectionView? does not have a member named dequeueResuableCellWithReuseIdentifier`.

`UICollectionView?` is a completely different type than `UICollectionView`. It's an [optional](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_496), and it definitely does not have the same methods defined on it as `UICollectionView`!

Looking at [the API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDataSource_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDataSource/collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:), that delegate method isn't defined to take optionals. Try removing the `?`s.

The reason is that the entirety of Cocoa APIs (a huge amount) have to be hand-checked for optional conformance, which is still an ongoing process. This leads to API changes between Xcode versions.